# Xamarin - Droid (SurfaceView)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, surfaceview

I have an app for face detection, thus I need to open the camera when the app is launched, I have looked into the similar problems yet I can't find a solution to the problem I currently have now. The problem is that the function **SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)** is not being called, thus, the camera is not being launched. Thanks for the response

**`CameraLayout.axml`**

```
<AppName.Droid.CameraControls.CameraLiveStream
      android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</App2.Droid.CameraControls.CameraLiveStream>
```

The CameraLiveStream.cs inherits **ViewGroup, ISurfaceHolderCallback2**

**`CameraLiveStream.cs`**

```
    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private bool mStartRequested;
    private bool mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    public CameraLiveStream(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mStartRequested = false;
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        mSurfaceView.Holder.AddCallback(this);

        AddView(mSurfaceView);
    }
    #region camera-surface
    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        mSurfaceAvailable = true;

        try
        {
            StartCameraIfReady();
        }
        catch
        {
            Log.Error("CameraLiveStream", "Error when starting camera");
        }
    }
```

Here's my **`MainActivity.cs OnCreate()`**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CameraLayout);

        mPreview = FindViewById<CameraLiveStream>(Resource.Id.cameraPreview);

        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == Permission.Granted)
        {
            CreateCameraSource();
        }
        else
        {
            RequestCameraPermissions();
        }

    }
```

**`CreateCameraSource`** Function

```
private void CreateCameraSource()
    {
        var context = Application.Context;
        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
                .SetClassificationType(ClassificationType.All)
                .Build();

        if (!detector.IsOperational)
        {
            Log.Warn("MainActivity", "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");
        }

        mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
                .SetRequestedPreviewSize(200, 200)
                                        .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                .SetRequestedFps(30.0f)
                .Build();

    }
```

**`StartCameraSource`** Function

```
private void StartCameraSource()
    {
        int code = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
                this.ApplicationContext);
        if (code != ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            Dialog dlg =
                    GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
            dlg.Show();
        }

        if (mCameraSource != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mPreview.StartCamera(mCameraSource);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("MainActivity-StartCameraSource", "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                mCameraSource.Release();
                mCameraSource = null;
            }
```

Comment: You are creating a SurfaceView with no layout params and thus its size it 0,0 and thus a surface would never need to be created

Comment: @SushiHangover Even though I have overriden the method OnLayout? 
    `protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
     {}` or should I really use 
`surface.setLayoutParams(params);` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue:

I have created another type of view underneath my 
**AppName.Droid.CameraControls.CameraLiveStream**

So it became like this

```
<AppName.Droid.Camera.Controls.CameraLiveStream>
      <AppName.Droid.Camera.Controls.Overlay>
      </AppName.Droid.Camera.Controls.Overlay>
</AppName.Droid.Camera.Controls.CameraLiveStream>
```

Wherein I the overlay inherited the View which implements the width/height of the view.

```
public int mPrevWidth { get => mWidth; set => mWidth = value; }
    public int mPrevHeight { get => mHeight; set => mHeight = value; }
    public float mPrevWidthScaleFactor { get => mWidthScaleFactor; set => mWidthScaleFactor = value; }
    public float mPrevHeightScaleFactor { get => mHeightScaleFactor; set => mHeightScaleFactor = value; }
    public CameraFacing mCameraFacing { get => mFacing; set => mFacing = value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a SurfaceView with no layout params and thus its size it 0,0 and thus a surface would never need to be created.

#### Full screen:

```
var layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
var view = new SurfaceView(someContext)
{
    LayoutParameters = layoutParams
};
```

#### Or Parent the SurfaceView to a *container* in your layout

```
var aViewGroup = FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.Id.SomeContainer);
aViewGroup.AddView(yourSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```